# How do I extract all HTML tags from a webpage into an array?

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, extract

I need to extract all HTML tags from a webpage into an array **without the data inside the tags**. It would look something like...

I'm using PHP

```
Array 
{
   html =>
             Array 
             {
                 head =>
                          Array
                          {
                              title,
                              meta name='description' content='bla bla'
                              meta name='keyword' content='bla bla'
                              ....
                          },
                 body =>
                          Array
                          {
                              div id='header' =>
                                              Array
                                              {
                                                  div class='logo',
                                                  div class='nav'
                                              },
                              div id='content' =>
                                              Array
                                              {
                                                  h1,
                                                  p class='first-para',
                                                  p,
                                                  p,
                                                  div id='ad'
                                              },
                              div id='footer' =>
                                              Array
                                              {
                                                  ul =>
                                                        Array
                                                        {
                                                            li =>
                                                                  Array
                                                                  {
                                                                     a href='link.htm'
                                                                  },
                                                            li =>
                                                                  Array
                                                                  {
                                                                     a href='link.htm'
                                                                  },
                                                            li =>
                                                                  Array
                                                                  {
                                                                     a href='link.htm'
                                                                  }
                                                        }
                                              }
                          }

             }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an HTML parser (an XML parser would probably not do because HTML often is invalid). Maybe: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: DOM can load real world HTML fine when you use `loadHTML()`. That seems to be a common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [PHP DOM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use XPath.

```
//*::name()
```

Should give you the names of all nodes on all levels. Iam not sure wheather not hierarchy will be flattened though.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? I just executed it in my console in Firefox on this page and got a basically empty return value.